# Multiple docker containers elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, elastic-beanstalk

I'm running my Play Scala app on Elastic Beanstalk using a single container Docker. The thing is, if I SSH into my instance, and run `docker ps`, I see this:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                              COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
b97459277e72        aws_beanstalk/current-app:latest   "/bin/sh -c 'rm -f R   10 minutes ago      Up 10 minutes       9000/tcp            cranky_rosalind     
7ffa795d6810        3dfb5143a62a                       "/bin/sh -c 'rm -f R   13 minutes ago      Up 13 minutes       9000/tcp            serene_sinoussi     
bbf010d8f02d        3dfb5143a62a                       "/bin/sh -c 'rm -f R   14 minutes ago      Up 14 minutes       9000/tcp            fervent_hawking     
ec9c3d329d1d        3dfb5143a62a                       "/bin/sh -c 'rm -f R   15 minutes ago      Up 15 minutes       9000/tcp            insane_hypatia      
9ffa80f40fec        3dfb5143a62a                       "/bin/sh -c 'rm -f R   16 minutes ago      Up 16 minutes       9000/tcp            admiring_rosalind
```

Should there be that many running containers?

Shouldn't there only be 1 container?

This is what my Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM java:openjdk-8-jre
MAINTAINER XXXX
EXPOSE 9000
ADD files /
WORKDIR /opt/docker
RUN ["chown", "-R", "daemon", "."]
USER daemon
ENTRYPOINT rm -f RUNNING_PID && bin/my-app -mem 1360 -DapplyEvolutions.default=true
CMD []
```

Here's the `docker ps` for another server using the same Dockerfile:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                              COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
bf33b51b6d59        aws_beanstalk/current-app:latest   "/bin/sh -c 'rm -f R   4 hours ago         Up 4 hours          9000/tcp            tender_leakey       
248664ebd789        aws_beanstalk/current-app:latest   "/bin/sh -c 'rm -f R   4 hours ago         Up 4 hours          9000/tcp            pensive_lumiere     
99a143adff26        aws_beanstalk/current-app:latest   "/bin/sh -c 'rm -f R   4 hours ago         Up 4 hours          9000/tcp            sad_poincare        
eb24ae106aed        aws_beanstalk/current-app:latest   "/bin/sh -c 'rm -f R   4 hours ago         Up 4 hours          9000/tcp            loving_fermi        
724552fdb751        aws_beanstalk/current-app:latest   "/bin/sh -c 'rm -f R   4 hours ago         Up 4 hours          9000/tcp            stoic_goldstine     
dd28117efa4a        aws_beanstalk/current-app:latest   "/bin/sh -c 'rm -f R   4 hours ago         Up 4 hours          9000/tcp            sad_pare            
05c74f0fe25f        aws_beanstalk/current-app:latest   "/bin/sh -c 'rm -f R   4 hours ago         Up 4 hours          9000/tcp            nostalgic_yonath    
cd1ae904efa6        aws_beanstalk/current-app:latest   "/bin/sh -c 'rm -f R   4 hours ago         Up 4 hours          9000/tcp            sad_hoover
```

Comment: There should be only one container running. Did you start the 3dfb5 image for some reason?

Comment: No, as far as I can tell they get started automatically.

Comment: You can try to stop and delete all the containers and run the container with a name by setting `--name` option.

Comment: @xuhdev: Right, but I want to prevent this from happening every time a new instance is spun up.

Comment: I meant to say that you can run a named container so you can have a better idea of what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason you're seeing so many is because they're failing to start up and get restarted. 
I have never seen anyone using `ENTRYPOINT cmd1 && cmd2`

Try moving your start-up sequence into a separate `start.sh` script and use that one as an `ENTRYPOINT` instead.